# What is shortcut for uncomment in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

Old way with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works for commenting but old way <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> not working anymore for uncomment, if anyone know new shortcut I will be grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: have you checked to make sure you didn't overwrite the shortcut's key binding?

Comment: There is no Visual Studio 2018. Please post your version. Use the correct tag with version number if possible.

Comment: Visual Studio 1.25.1

Comment: I did not change anything in the configuration, I only updated regular updates.

Comment: version 1.25.1 on w7 64bit

Comment: You are not talking about "Visual Studio". You are talking about "Visual Studio Code". That's two completely different products.

Comment: Try CTRL+/ to toggle comments on and off.

Comment: Now on Linux Ubuntu everything works as expected but on windows doesnt.

Answer (score 57):

I just updated my VSCode to the version you mentioned. The combinations work exactly as you described. It must be something that was changed on your computer.

Go to <kbd>File</kbd> => <kbd>Preferences</kbd> => <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd>

(Or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)

look for `Remove Line Comment`. In my settings it still says

[image]

If your VSCode has a different keybinding, change it back to what you want.

Comment: In my is the same but command not working.Never mind,i will use CRTL + SHIFT + /  for commenting multi lines and same for uncomment.This shortcut works.Thanks.

Comment: not working for me as well. Same issue as the above user9160346

Comment: check if you have two same combination of keys - one for remove line comment and the other one for transform to uppercase. Remove the latter and everything works again;)

Comment: It is working for me. And yea it is the default keybinding , if anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 44):

I had the same problem. In the newer version its actually <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to uncomment.

Comment: I agreed,now i am using Ubuntu 16.04 and everything works well,i think than windows isnt the best solution for web development.Here works properly both CTRL+K CTRL+C for comment and CTRL+U for uncomment.

Comment: Hi @GoranIlic thanks for your feedback. I suppose it's then slightly different for different operating systems. I was using windows at the time of answering this question.

Comment: Now on my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 works fine as expected.

Comment: It works for me, but this one is for toggle i suppose.

Answer (score 18):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Note that this is the <kbd>/</kbd> on the numeric keypad!

Answer (score 14):

Mac OS you can use `COMMAND` + `/` for commenting and uncommenting

Comment: How to remove multiline comments in Mac OS `/*  */` ?

Comment: @Jos - `Shift + option + A`

Comment: Same on linux Mint

Comment: `cnrl + shift + a` to wrap/unwrap in docstrings.

Answer (score 9):

**In windows** Inorder to **comment and uncomment the code in VS CODE**

1. **CTRL + K**     ========> to comment the code
2. **CTRL + /**     ========> to uncomment the code

Answer (score 6):

For windows:

**Remove Comment Line**:- ctrl+k ctrl+u

Comment: Thanks, that one worked for me. Even in VS 2022 Community Version. :-)

Answer (score 4):

use ctrl+ / to uncomment in VS Code.

Answer (score 4):

In windows system, below commands works for me for comment and uncomment in VS CODE-

`CTRL + K` --- to comment OR `CTRL + /` ---to comment

`CTRL + /` --- to uncomment

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, I am using `strg + #`

It's a default shortcut in VSCode --> toggle line comment 
but it works also for blocks.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS just select all the stuff you want to comment or uncomment and press Command + /

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is :
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS code on **Mac**, Version: 1.49.0 and I had similar problem.
In my case shortcut "cmd + k, cmd + u" made text uppercase. It turned out I have two commands assigned to this shortcut.
In "Keyboard Shortcuts" you can also **filter by shortcuts** (or "Keybindings") by pressing keyboard icon on the right in the search bar, it will record keys:

[image]

To fix this, I just changed "Transform to Uppercase" Keybinding to something else as I rarely use it.

Comment: Exactly the same situation here. Should probably be the accepted answer. Switching to another combination of keys is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take care. Some extensions change the keyboard shortcuts. Take a look in the attached screenshot. I don't know what extension changed mine to Shift + Ctrl + K on Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend instead of using separate shortcuts for add/remove comment to set toggle line/block comment with the same shortcut so it also remove comment when the line/block is commented out:

- `editor.action.commentLine`
- `editor.action.blockComment`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Ctrl + /
```

for both comment and uncomment the code in vscode

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for both comment and uncomment.

Also here is the cheatsheet with all shortcuts.
https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf